# Recently deleted my AVD and did not get back the 8 GB it took up?

Tags: android-emulator, avd-manager, android-studio

I haven't used Android Studio in a few months so I went ahead and deleted my AVD and system image from the tools menu inside Android Studio. The image deleted fine, however I notice that while the AVD was gone, I did not get back the ~8 GB it took up. I also see that my pagefile.sys has grown to roughly the same size.

Is this due to the AVD using this as virtual memory and not reallocating it back to my hard drive after deletion? I can manually go into settings and change my pagefile.sys size but I want to make sure that this was a result of the AVD initial install before I mess around with my partitions. I vaguely remember Android Studio asking about RAM allocation for optimal AVD performance during the initial install.

Comment: pagefile.sys size is automatically determined by the OS. It seems that your system does not have sufficient RAM and therefore starting the Android emulator increased the pagefile.sys size. Android Studio respectively AVD don't have an direct influence on the pagefile size, this was just because your system lacks physical RAM. For working with Android studio + emulator you should have a minimum of 8GB RAM better 16. You can manually set the page file size in Windows system settings to a smaller value and afterwards back to "auto" to shrink it.